# Half of the HTC EVO 4G screen is unresponsive

Tags: screen, htc-evo

I have a HTC EVO 4G, which I got around 6 months ago.

Just recently, the lower half of my phone's screen has become almost completely unresponsive.

For instance, I wanted to allow the use of non-market apps. The confirmation screen that tells me that this could potentially be dangerous is not selectable because of the screen being non-responsive.

How can I fix this? Do I send it back to be repaired?

Comment: As a quick work-around to be able to e.g. confirm that popup you've mentioned: have your tried changing the screen orientation? Turning the device upside-down might enable you to do so, as then the upper half is the "broken one". As for the fact itself: I'd say you'll have to turn it in for repair. Sounds like a hardware issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your digitizer probably failed.  That is the glass piece you touch with your finger.  On some models it can be replaced, although not something for the faint of heart.  I have had to do this for my EVO 3D.

Comment: It's possible, but it's been rated difficult: [Replace guide on iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+HTC+Evo+4G+Front+Panel/3081/1)